# Property does not exist on type, when it clearly does

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-class

I'm writing my code in Typescript, and I'm trying to access property named id on any object that implements an interface named ObjectTemplate.

Let's say I have an class `Player`, that implements `ObjectTemplate`, that has an id property. Then, I pass `new Player()` into `addObject()` function I have provided below.

When I try to access the `new Player().id` (or as I named it in my parameter, `obj.id`), I get an error telling me that `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ObjectTemplate'`

```js
interface ObjectTemplate {
    id: string
}

class Player implements ObjectTemplate {
    id: string
    name: string
    
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

class Entity implements ObjectTemplate {
    id: string
    health: number
    
    constructor(health: number) {
        this.health = health
    }
}

const createId = () => 'randomId'


class ObjectList<ObjectTemplate> {
    objects: { [key: string]: ObjectTemplate }

    constructor() {
        this.objects = {}
    }

    addObject(obj: ObjectTemplate) {
        const newId = createId()
        
        obj.id = newId // I get an error here.
        
        this.objects[newId] = obj
    }
}

const playerList: ObjectList<Player> = new ObjectList()
playerList.addObject(new Player("someName"))

const entityList: ObjectList<Entity> = new ObjectList()
entityList.addObject(new Entity(100))
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=46&pc=38#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgCoQC2ADgDZyTIDeAUMvcsACYBcyAzmFKAOY0C%20NGgnLt2yAArkAntEYlSRCOHEZsuAgoopaDRqw5dedBiDiEIbTtxB89J%20ggD2IawFdcTqAAozFq0a2AJTUDnrIYAAWwOwAdH4oALzICWGCgsKi4gCi4MBg0vJkSipoWDj4RGTaoXrMATZ2DJEQcKRRbCBuhOjQYWHOrlweYF7eLW0dKd29UCG64fRRMbET7ZHIyWtRaQJCg5zICFCtkACSTJvI3iGJAHzIAORQcCBMToQXj0KZcGJl6jAABkYmAADxqCqaaqQB4LehOcq4dhsKjIADaAGsINIGrwALpsSEaKrkSgZPQHYaeHzzMJ6ZZxRGA8TJKiCPQUhhwJhMYlgbzMolIypaSB0xaOFyHEAQADuFyux1OEAuN3pDA1CKwsWYV1lCsuAHojZIoE5iNACk9mI9kO8IOIQE4wMgIAAPUHIFwRaSWp786FkiDfSXILURaJMkXsdEGi74q7M3YZKnIaqyKAgzjCwHZ8FSOCZh7JA0Air59UZ6D52I8vki3zyyQyaDeABE7A%20EAAcuYIO2gkF9tLXcowPlpPncxXQWDchOCiWUs3%20ZXh%20PJ7X6-ym3LkAvJ94AIwABlPQ6AA)

Comment: @ThomasSablik, that's incorrect, the `new` operator has higher precedence than the `.` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your template syntax is wrong. You're declaring ObjectList with a new type named ObjectTemplate, and not a type that implements/extends ObjectTemplate.

```
interface ObjectTemplate {
    id: string
}

class Player implements ObjectTemplate {
    id: string
    name: string
    
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.id = '0';
        this.name = name
    }
}

class Entity implements ObjectTemplate {
    id: string
    health: number
    
    constructor(health: number) {
        this.id = '0';
        this.health = health
    }
}

const createId = () => 'randomId'


class ObjectList<T extends ObjectTemplate> {
    objects: { [key: string]: T }

    constructor() {
        this.objects = {}
    }

    addObject(obj: T) {
        const newId = createId()
        
        obj.id = newId // I get an error here.
        
        this.objects[newId] = obj
    }
}

const playerList: ObjectList<Player> = new ObjectList()
playerList.addObject(new Player("someName"))

const entityList: ObjectList<Entity> = new ObjectList()
entityList.addObject(new Entity(100))
```

I don't know typescript, but this is what I got from reading the docs:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Yes,  in OP's code `ObjectTemplate` is not the interface but the template parameter. That's why it doesn't have the property `id`.